# Drupal 7 - how to add unique class name to each page?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I'm second day into Drupal and pretty confused... I need to add an unique class name to the body tag to identify each page as there are many unique styling (to repeating elements) on each page across the site.

I've found a couple of code snippets online but they haven't worked. For example I've added this into the `template.php` file, but it doesn't work:

```
function testtheme_preprocess_html(&$vars) { // my theme is called "testtheme"
  $path = drupal_get_path_alias($_GET['q']);
  $aliases = explode('/', $path);

  foreach($aliases as $alias) {
    $vars['classes_array'][] = drupal_clean_css_identifier($alias);
  } 
}
```

It's suppose to add a class to the body tag but nothing is showing up for me. Am I missing something or can someone provide another solution?

Comment: Did you clear the cache after adding the function in your template.php?

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/50247/page-id-based-on-file-path/50252#50252

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer of Rainfall is true but :
There are already unique class by page in drupal in body element page-NAMEPAGE

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I didn't understand you right, but you can add code to the body tag in your html.tpl.php file to make it look this way:

```
<body class="<?php print $classes; ?>" <?php print $attributes;?>>
```

And that's all. After that your body tag will automatic have css classes according to the page . Also you'll have info about node type, info about if user logged in, node id.

Let me know if it works or if I made some mistake.
Thanks and good luck!

Comment: Maybe cause of your code you've "broken" something. Maybe good idea will be to delete it to how it was at the beginning and place code I've put there to html.tpl.php ?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify https://www.drupal.org/project/node_class module:

1) comment function node_class_preprocess_node in node_class.module

2) insert

```
$node_classes = node_class($node);
if (!empty($node_classes)) $node_classes .= ' ';
$content_column_class = str_replace(' class="','', $content_column_class);
$content_column_class = ' class="'. $node_classes . $content_column_class;
```

in page.tpl.php
before

```
<section<?php print $content_column_class; ?> id="content_col">
```